# How can I get 0x1b87 to print like \x1b\x87 in Python?

Tags: python, hex

How can I get `0x1b87` to print like `\x1b\x87` in Python?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hex(0x0d90 ^ 0x1617)
'0x1b87'
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to use `format(..., 'x')` for hexadecimal representation, avoiding the unnecessary slicing (`hex(...)[2:]`).

### Python 2

Just decode the string (using the [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) codec):

```
>>> format(0x0d90 ^ 0x1617, 'x').decode('hex')
'\x1b\x87'
```

or pack the integer with [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) (`>` for big-endian order, `H` for `unsigned short` - change [format character](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) to meet your requirements)

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>H', 0x0d90 ^ 0x1617)
'\x1b\x87'
```

### Python 3

[`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) does that:

```
In [1]: bytes.fromhex(format(0x0d90 ^ 0x1617, 'x'))
Out[1]: b'\x1b\x87'
```

[`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) is still an option, [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings) are as for Python 2 (see the previous section):

```
In [2]: import struct

In [3]: struct.pack('>H', 0x0d90 ^ 0x1617)
Out[3]: b'\x1b\x87'
```

The `hex` codec is now one of the [binary transforms](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms), use [`codecs.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode):

```
In [4]: import codecs

In [5]: codecs.decode(format(0x0d90 ^ 0x1617, 'x'), 'hex')
Out[5]: b'\x1b\x87'
```

### Python 3.2 and newer

Python 3.2 introduced the cool [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method:

```
In [4]: (0x0d90 ^ 0x1617).to_bytes(4, 'big')
Out[4]: b'\x00\x00\x1b\x87'
```

It will produce a fixed number of bytes (*4* in this example) or the `OverflowError` "if the integer is not representable with the given number of bytes".

There's a way to calculate the minimum number of bytes necessary to represent the integer:

```
In [22]: i = 0x0d90 ^ 0x1617

In [23]: i.to_bytes((i.bit_length() // 8) + 1, 'big')
Out[23]: b'\x1b\x87'
```

Also, consider specifying the `signed` argument that

> determines whether two's complement
>   is used to represent the integer.  If *signed* is *False* and a negative
>   integer is given, an *OverflowError* is raised.

Answer (score 2):

```
import struct
struct.pack(">H" ,int('0x1b87',16))

'\x1b\x87'
>>>
```